# How to send input from a MouseListener to another class?

Tags: java, class, mouse

I have a runner class that runs the splashscreen and then runs the main menu. From the main menu, different screens should appear depending on the option the user has selected.

The problem is that I use `MouseListener`s to detect which option the user has clicked on. This value then needs to be passed on to the runner class to determine which class to display next.

I cannot get this to work in an efficient method. At the moment, I have it where it gets the mouse location at the very beginning of execution and never looks for it again. I also tried with a while loop that did [while the mouse position is not on top of a button get the mouse position again] but obviously we do not want to use while loops as that is inefficient.

Several other threads on this site have suggested to make what would be my runner class implement the interface then parameter-pass it to the main menu... this however does not make much sense to me because shouldn't a runner class not be a subclass or implement any interfaces?

Here is my code:

**Main menu class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;

public class MainMenu extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener{ //ActionListener?
  Image image;
  int loc = 0;

  public MainMenu(){
    initializeImage();
    addMouse();
  }

  public void initializeImage(){
    try{
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("MainMenu.jpg"));
      //JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
      //add(picLabel);
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
  }

  public int getLoc()
  {
   return loc; 
  }

  public void addMouse(){
    addMouseListener
      (new MouseAdapter()
                       {
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
      {
        loc = e.getY();
      }                
    }
    );
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { //Add proposed helper method!
        if (e.getX() >= 200 && e.getX() <= 800){
          try{
            if (e.getY() >= 241 && e.getY() <= 309){
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("MainMenu1.jpg"));  
              repaint();
            }
            else if (e.getY() >= 349 && e.getY() <= 412){
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("MainMenu2.jpg"));  
              repaint();
            }
            else if (e.getY() >= 451 && e.getY() <= 516){
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("MainMenu3.jpg"));  
              repaint();
            }
            else if (e.getY() >= 552 && e.getY() <= 619){
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("MainMenu4.jpg"));  
              repaint();
            }
            else{
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("MainMenu.jpg"));  
              repaint();
            }
          }
          catch(IOException ee){}

        }
      }
    });
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters            
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){}

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

**Runner class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
/** 
  * @author Horatiu Lazu
  * Incomplete class.*/

public class ClassRunner extends JFrame{

  public ClassRunner(){
    setSize(960, 661);
    LevelSelection l = new LevelSelection();
    add(l);
    setVisible(true); 
  }

  public static void main (String [] args){
    new ClassRunner();
  }
}
```

Comment: No, just no :) Use `JButton`s with `ActionListener`s.

Comment: @user1803551 Full ack!